# Why do these two statements have different execution results in python?About map function

Tags: python, list

```py
def preorder(t):
    """Return a list of the entries in this tree in the order that they
    would be visited by a preorder traversal (see problem description).

    >>> numbers = tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3, [tree(4), tree(5)]), tree(6, [tree(7)])])
    >>> preorder(numbers)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    >>> preorder(tree(2, [tree(4, [tree(6)])]))
    [2, 4, 6]
    """
    order = [label(t)]

    # map(lambda x:order.extend(x), list(map(preorder, branches(t))))
    # This is the first statement.
    
    
    # orders = list(map(preorder, branches(t)))
    # for elem in orders:
    #     order.extend(elem)
    # the other one.
    
    return order

def tree(label, branches=[]):
    """Construct a tree with the given label value and a list of branches."""
    for branch in branches:
        assert is_tree(branch), 'branches must be trees'
    return [label] + list(branches)

def label(tree):
    """Return the label value of a tree."""
    return tree[0]

def branches(tree):
    """Return the list of branches of the given tree."""
    return tree[1:]
```

When executing the preoder function, the first statement executed doctest returned `[1]`, and the result was wrong.
The second statement returns `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Return a list of the entries in this tree in the order that they would be visited by a preorder traversal

The following is the expected result

```
>>> numbers = tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3, [tree(4), tree(5)]), tree(6, [tree(7)])])
>>> preorder(numbers)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> preorder(tree(2, [tree(4, [tree(6)])]))
[2, 4, 6]
"""
```

Comment: What are `branches` and `label`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator. This means it only executes the mapping function if the result is requested.

```
map(lambda x:order.extend(x), list(map(preorder, branches(t))))
```

The outer `map` is never asked for its results, so it doesn't do anything while the inner `map` would be asked by the outer one. Therefore you can write it as:

```
list(map(lambda x:order.extend(x), map(preorder, branches(t))))
```

to make it work because `list` collects all items from an iterator to create a list from them.